# Issue with program involving sockets and client-server communication in C

Tags: c, sockets, server, directory, client

I am working on a program in C that involves client-server connections and communication between the two parties.

The program involves the client sending a letter to the server and the server getting the letter. The server then searches through the current file directory (in linux) for a file beginning with that letter and sends the client the number of bytes of the file and the text of the file.

The overall program is very long and for the assignment the instructor already did much of the code such as setting up the sockets and creating the entire program for the client side of operations.

For the server side I had to write code for:

- getting the file descriptor from the passed memory and casting it

-getting the letter from the client

-Attempting to open the current directory

-Iterating through the directory looking for a file that starts with the letter

-Attempting to open the file and sending the size of the file and number of bytes of file to the client in network endian

-Closing the file and directory after finishing

-Error checking: there are error checking statements if the directory cannot be opened, the file cannot be opened, or no matching file is found

The following is my code with comments

```
void*           handleClient    (void*  vPtr
                                )
{
  //  I.  Application validity check:

       int      fd              = *((int *) vPtr); 
     //casting vPtr to an int//

        free(vPtr);


//  II.  Handle the client:

        char buffer[BUFFER_LEN+1];
        read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_LEN+1);
        //read the letter into a buffer//

        const char* dirNamePtr = ".";
        DIR* dirPtr = opendir(dirNamePtr);
//   Open the current directory


        if (dirPtr == NULL)
        {
            int toSend = htonl(CANT_READ_DIR_CODE);
                write(fd,&toSend,sizeof(toSend));
                printf("Cannot read directory\n");
                return(NULL);
        }
// If current directory cannot be opened, it sends a error message in network // endian to the client

        struct dirent* entryPtr;
        char path[BUFFER_LEN];
        struct stat statBuffer;
//implements struct dirent to get info on the directory

//iterates through the directory
        while ((entryPtr=readdir(dirPtr)) != NULL)
        {


           stat(entryPtr->d_name, &statBuffer);
//puts in metaddata of the current directory into statbuffer


          if (!S_ISREG(statBuffer.st_mode))
                continue;
//if the entry is not a file, continue

// if the first letter of the file is not the character received from the //client, send an error mesage

          if(entryPtr->d_name[0]!=buffer[0])  {
                   int toSend2 = htonl(NO_MATCH_CODE);
                   write(fd,&toSend2,sizeof(toSend2));
                   printf("No matching file\n");
                   return(NULL);
               }


                int ab;
                int numRead;
                int numBytes;
                char buffer[BUFFER_LEN];
//open the file and send bytes of file and file size to client

            if (entryPtr->d_name[0]==buffer[0] &(S_ISREG(statBuffer.st_mode)))
                {

                        ab=open(entryPtr->d_name,O_RDONLY,0660);

                        if(ab<0) {
                                int toSend3 = htonl(CANT_READ_FILE_CODE);
                                write(fd,&toSend3, sizeof(toSend3));
                                printf("Cannot read <filename>\n");
                                return(NULL);
                                }

                        numBytes=htonl(statBuffer.st_size);
                        write(fd, &numBytes, sizeof(numBytes));

                        printf("Sending %s, %d bytes\n",entryPtr >d_name,statBuffer.st_size);


                while((numBytes=read(ab,buffer,BUFFER_LEN))>0)
                        {
                                printf("We read %d bytes\n", numBytes);
                                write(fd, buffer, numBytes);
                        }
//close the fiel

                       close(ab);

                }
                break;

//leave the loop





}

 //  III.  Finished:
//

closedir(dirPtr);

return(NULL);
}
```

My code compiles but does not send the file to the client when I try running it. I have tried several different letters and it has not worked for any of them. I do not quite know what the issue is which makes it difficult to fix my mistakes.

I am not asking for the answer or anything, just help in seeing where I am wrong. I appreciate any help.

Comment: This looks to be ideal for your debugger. Does your program actually announce it's sending the file, but fail to do so? Or does it simply announce "No matching file" . Or.. none of the above and rather something else? This seems like it would be pretty simple to instrument with a ton of output messaging, and of course, churn in a debugger.

Comment: It announces "No matching file" whenever I attempt to send the file  I have used a printf statement and entryPtr->d_name[0] always prints the letter m.

Comment: Wait. This is supposed to enumerate the folder and send only files that match the first letter right? What if the first file *doesn't* match the letter? The function just exists (rather harshly too, I might add; it doesn't closedir or anything). In other words, as soon as the first non-match file is encountered, send a message and it's game over. Was that intentional? The loop control looks just odd.  And that `break` or that entire `f(entryPtr->d_name[0]!=buffer[0])` section just looks off.

Comment: I thought that might be the issue. Do you have any idea on how I can keep iterating if the first file does not match the letter? I do close the directory in the end after the while loop finishes.

Comment: Sure just `continue` if the first character doesn't match. Move the no-file-sent message after the loop, conditionally executed only if `entryPtr` is null (meaning you enumerated the whole folder and never sent a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic for when to send vs. when to send no-file status seems wrong. I *think* it should be like this (fair warning, I didn't test this, or even compile it beyond basic syntax checking, but you should get the idea):

```
void* handleClient(void*  vPtr)
{
    //  I.  Application validity check:
    int fd = *((int *) vPtr);
    free(vPtr);

    //  II.  Handle the client:
    char buffer[BUFFER_LEN+1];
    read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_LEN+1);
    //read the letter into a buffer//

    const char* dirNamePtr = ".";
    DIR* dirPtr = opendir(dirNamePtr);
    //   Open the current directory

    if (dirPtr == NULL)
    {
        int toSend = htonl(CANT_READ_DIR_CODE);
        write(fd,&toSend,sizeof(toSend));
        printf("Cannot read directory\n");
        return(NULL);
    }

    struct dirent* entryPtr;
    char path[BUFFER_LEN];
    struct stat statBuffer;
    //implements struct dirent to get info on the directory

    //iterates through the directory
    while ((entryPtr=readdir(dirPtr)) != NULL)
    {
        stat(entryPtr->d_name, &statBuffer);
        //puts in metaddata of the current directory into statbuffer

        // if this isn't a regular file OR the first char doesn't match...
        if (!S_ISREG(statBuffer.st_mode) || entryPtr->d_name[0]!=buffer[0])
            continue;

        int ab;
        int numRead;
        int numBytes;
        char buffer[BUFFER_LEN];
        //open the file and send bytes of file and file size to client

        ab = open(entryPtr->d_name,O_RDONLY,0660);

        if(ab<0) {
            int toSend3 = htonl(CANT_READ_FILE_CODE);
            write(fd,&toSend3, sizeof(toSend3));
            printf("Cannot read <filename>\n");
            closedir(dirPtr);
            return(NULL);
        }

        numBytes=htonl(statBuffer.st_size);
        write(fd, &numBytes, sizeof(numBytes));

        printf("Sending %s, %d bytes\n",entryPtr >d_name,statBuffer.st_size);
        while((numBytes=read(ab,buffer,BUFFER_LEN))>0)
        {
            printf("We read %d bytes\n", numBytes);
            write(fd, buffer, numBytes);
        }

        //close the file and leave
        close(ab);
        break;
    }

    // if this is NULL it means we dind't send anything. we break the loop
    //  when a file to send it discovered.
    if (entryPtr == NULL)
    {
        printf("No matching file\n");
        int toSend2 = htonl(NO_MATCH_CODE);
        write(fd, &toSend2, sizeof(toSend2));
    }

    //  III.  Finished:
    closedir(dirPtr);

    return(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I re-compiled my code with the edits to the syntax and now it is sending information about the file to the client! I will learn from the syntax errors I made and how it impaired the flow of my program. Thank you.